# Backorder Message Appearing Twice

Tags: magento, cart

For some reason my configurable product has the "backorder" message appearing twice on the cart page.  I tracked down the error message to this Mage code:

```
if ($this->getBackorders() == Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::BACKORDERS_YES_NOTIFY) {
    if (!$this->getIsChildItem()) {
        $result->setMessage(
            Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('This product is not available in the requested quantity. %s of the items will be backordered.', ($backorderQty * 1))
        );
    } else {
        $result->setMessage(
           Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('"%s" is not available in the requested quantity. %s of the items will be backordered.', $this->getProductName(), ($backorderQty * 1))
        );
    }
}
```

I'm getting each of those messages.  It's like it's checking twice for the same product, once for the configurable and once for the simple.

I figure this is a configuration issue and not something in the code I should need to change.  What would cause this weird behavior?

Comment: You might try adding some var_dump($this) or var_dump($this->debug()) statements into that core file temporarily to try to find out if its being called multiple times. The logic above can't run both lines. 

Also, make sure that the configurable product quantities are properly set. Try 0 for them all. Try 1. etc. Without getting into your system, it's going to be hard to diagnose.

Comment: That code runs two times, so two message will be printed out. One for simple product (child of configurable product) and one for the configurable product itself.

Answer (score 0):

did you rewrite the Mage_Model_CatalogInventory_Observer class? and what version are you using?

Comment: you should write this on the comment portion not on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did that. `preg_match` the `message['text']` with backordered and control it. Here is the code for you

```
    $i=0;
    foreach ($messages as $message):

      $txt= $message['text'] ;
      $re='(backordered)';  # Word 3

    if (preg_match_all ("/".$re."/is", $txt, $matches))
      { if($i == 0){?>
            <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">* <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']); ?></p>
     <?php }
     }
     else
     { ?>
      <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">* <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></p>
    <?php }
     $i++;
    endforeach;
```